# Can OpenXML be used to launch a new Word instance?

Tags: ms-word, openxml-sdk

I'm able to generate Word documents without issue. I save the resulting *.docx file to a temporary location and then need to launch the file in Word.

The requirement is to not "open" the file in Word (easily done with a **Process.Start**) but to have load into Word as a *new unsaved* file. This is because certain propriety integrations for Word need to take over when a user saves the file and don't kick in if the file is ready saved but to a location on disk.

I've achieved this by using Interop calls to the Word application, adding the new document to Word's workspace. My problem is with Interop which tends to break on various client machines, particularly when Office upgrades take place (say a client had 32-bit office but upgraded with a 64-bit version).

I'm somewhat new to OpenXML, but can it be used to automate Word or is Interop my only real option?

```
object oFilename = tmpFileName;
object oNewTemplate = false;
object oDocumentType = 0;
object oVisible = true;
Document document = _application.Documents.Add(ref oFilename, ref oNewTemplate, ref oDocumentType, ref oVisible);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Open XML technology has no way of interacting with the Office (Word) application - it's for file creation/manipulation, only. The interop is required in order to do anything with the Word application.

There is sort of a way around this - and it's only possible with Word, no other Office application has this - is to convert the Open XML content to the OPC flat-file format. This "concatenates" the various packages that make up the zip file to a pure text string, essetially a single XML file.

XML content in the OPC flat-file format can then be written to an *already opened* (even newly created) Word document using the `Range.InsertXML` method via "the interop". In a way, this "streams" the Open XML content into the opened Word document.

The problem with this approach is that certain document-level properties are *not* written to the target document, so not all aspects of the opened document can be changed. For example: page size, orientation, headers, footers... So if this kind of thing also needs to be affected the interop is required for such settings.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look deeper over the OPC file format. I just wish there were much easier fixes to Interop breaking on client workstations.

Comment: @MoSlo I'm not familiar with the interop "breaking" in connection with different bit-ness of the OS...? I didn't really want to get into that in Q&A as it would be "too broad" but can you give a concrete example of what breaks?

Comment: There are several variants where via Interop Word can't be "found" on the client machine, even though it launches fine when run buy human hands. One variant is the office lib entries in the registry are referencing the wrong location. In one case a user had a 32-bit copy of Office which was then upgraded to a later version of Office but the 64-bit version. I don't believe the OS version is to blame but the manner of the upgrade in that particular environment. I admit the exact case is speculation.

Comment: @MoSlo So the problem comes with code like `New Word.Application`? Not with the actual object model?

Comment: That is correct; if Interop isn't correctly registered on the desktop, that line would cause an error.